# Convert HashMap to Object containing list attributes

Tags: java, jackson, hashmap, gson, mapstruct

Is possible to convert this HashMap to the corresponding Object? Maybe using Jackson Object Mapper, Gson, or even Mapstruct. The trick here is how to map List attributes, that in my INPUT has a number as suffix in the attribute name:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
   put("fooName", "foo name");
   put("bars1.barName", "bar at position 0 name");
   put("bars1.barValue", "bar at position 0 value");
   put("bars2.barName", "bar at position 1 name");
   put("bars2.barValue", "bar at position 1 value");
}};
      
public class Foo {
    
    String fooName;
    List<Bar> bars;
// getters/setters    
}
    
public class Bar {
    
    String barName;
    String barValue;
// getters/setters
}
```

PS: this input comes from an external API call and I can't modify the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `@JsonAnySetter` annotation along with a map of Bar instances:

```
public class Foo {

    String fooName;
    private Map<Integer, Bar> map = new TreeMap<>();

    // getters/setters    
    public String getFooName() {
        return fooName;
    }
    public void setFooName(String fooName) {
        this.fooName = fooName;
    }
    public List<Bar> getBars() {
        return map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void bars(String key, String value) {
        String[] ids = key.split("\\.");
        if (ids[0].startsWith("bars")) {
            Integer barKey = Integer.parseInt(ids[0].substring("bars".length())) - 1;
            String field = ids[1];
            Bar bar = map.computeIfAbsent(barKey, k -> new Bar());
            if ("barName".equals(field)) {
                bar.setBarName(value);
            } else if ("barValue".equals(field)) {
                bar.setBarValue(value);
            }
            map.put(barKey, bar);               
        }  // else handle other properties
    }
}
```

Test:

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("fooName", "foo name");
    put("bars1.barName", "bar at position 0 name");
    put("bars1.barValue", "bar at position 0 value");
    put("bars2.barName", "bar at position 1 name");
    put("bars2.barValue", "bar at position 1 value");
}};

String json = m.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map);

Foo foo = m.readValue(json, Foo.class);

System.out.println("reserialized = " + m.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(foo));
```

output:

```
reserialized = {
  "fooName" : "foo name",
  "bars" : [ {
    "barName" : "bar at position 0 name",
    "barValue" : "bar at position 0 value"
  }, {
    "barName" : "bar at position 1 name",
    "barValue" : "bar at position 1 value"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intermediate hashmap for converting. Try the sample converter below.
Remark: You might want to use appropriate constructors for Foo and Bar or use setters (I used public fields for simplicity). And there is no error handling.

```
static Foo convertMap(Map<String, String> map){
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.fooName = map.remove("fooName");

    Map<String, Bar> barsMap = new HashMap<String, Bar>();

    for(String key : map.keySet()){
      String[] split = key.split("\\.");
      String name = split[0];
      String attribute = split[1];

      Bar bar = null;
      if(barsMap.containsKey(name)){
        bar = barsMap.get(name);
      }
      else{
        bar = new Bar();
        barsMap.put(name, bar);
      }

      switch(attribute){
        case "barName": bar.barName = map.get(key); break;
        case "barValue": bar.barValue = map.get(key); break;
        default: break;
      }
    }

    foo.bars = new ArrayList(barsMap.values());

    return foo;
  }
```